# Is it possible to find out what version of Nuget I have installed on my Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, nuget

I am trying to figure out what version of `nuget` I have installed on my mac. I am not sure where it is installed too so am struggling to find it and the [Nuget Command Line help page](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference) relates mainly to installing packages not the actual nuget package itself.

So is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O.k. I found how to do this. If you type

```
Nuget ?
```

it will print all the available commands and the Nuget version will be the first line of the printout

This is not actually contained in the documentation, but if it were to be at some stage it would be here: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference#help-command

Answer (score 5):

**On Windows I do: (should work on mac too)**

```
nuget ? v
```

[image]

The "v" command is actually not valid, but with this approach you only get the nuget version number and below the information that "v" is an unknow command.

---

**Mac PowerShell:**

```
nuget help | head -1
```

**Windows PowerShell:**

```
nuget help | select -First 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly for Nuget but you can try to find all your applications and version with this in command line :

```
system_profiler SPApplicationsDataType
```

Then do a cmd+f to find Nuget.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I'm affraid `Nuget` doesn't show up in the list after running this command. Probably because it's installed as part of another application (`Xamarin`)

Comment: Hum ok so the best way to find the version is to find where you installed it.
so first question is how did you installed it (as you said you don't know where it is) ? 
maybe it is in the Xamarin repository installed so you can check in there ?

Comment: Ok so I found its location. It was using `/usr/local/bin` which had a `nuget` shortcut which pointed to `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.2.3/bin/` which contained the nuget exec. How do I find the version of the exec file?

Answer (score 1):

$host command is used to find the version of the NuGet.

Check this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/policies/nuget-faq

clipped from the link:

```
How do I check the exact version of NuGet installed?
In Visual Studio, use the Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio command and look at the version displayed next to NuGet Package Manager.
Alternatively, launch the Package Manager Console (Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console) and enter $host to see information about NuGet including the version.
```

Comment: Does this also work on `Visual Studio for mac` or just `Visual Studio for windows`?

Comment: Its package manager command it should work in package manager console.